# Lambda doesn't execute all Promises

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, koa

My [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function pre-renders a [React](https://reactjs.org/) user interface for a Pets API. It's invoked by an [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) endpoint. I am adapting this project from the [cra-serverless](https://github.com/sbstjn/cra-serverless) project. The NodeJS server framework I'm using is [Koa](https://koajs.com/). I've made a async `handler` function to respond to client requests. It does 3 things:

1. Get the data from the Pet API and populate `getCatsResponse`.
2. Render the UI using the `getCatsResponse` object.
3. Store the cat items in a DynamoDB table for further processing.

I've noticed that this makes my requests take a long time to receive a response, and I suppose this question is a little open-ended, but I am hoping to get clarification on these 3 points:

1. Why aren't the items inserted into the table when I remove `Promise.all()` from the list of `Promise`s created by the `.map()` function?

   1. I thought that, since it's an asynchronous function call, the requests have been sent and there's no need to handle the respose. What am I misunderstanding?
2. Assuming I need to wait for all the `Promise`s to resolve, should I delegate that responsibility to another Lambda function?

   1. If so, I can just invoke that Lambda from this Lambda and forget about it (don't have to `await` for it to resolve), right?
3. When I set the `ctx.body`, that response is only sent once the Lambda has reached the end of the function, right?

```
import koa from 'koa'
import http from 'koa-route'
import serve from 'koa-static'

import App from '../src/App'
import { paths } from './config'
import { render } from './lib/render'
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import GetCatsResponse from '../typings/GetCatsResponse'

import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { Cat } from '../typings/Cat'

export const Router = new koa()
const DynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const handler = async (ctx: koa.Context) => {

  // Try Pet API
  let url = 'https://api.pets.com/v2/cats'
  let getCatsResponse: GetCatsResponse = Object.create(GetCatsResponse);
  await fetch(url).then((response: any) => response.json().then((jsonData: any) => {
    getCatsResponse = jsonData;
  }));
  console.log(getCatsResponse);

  // Render response body 
  ctx.body = render(getCatsResponse, App, ctx.request.path)

  // Enter item into DynamoDB
  return Promise.all(getCatsResponse.items.map((catResponse) => {
    const input: AWS.DynamoDB.PutItemInput = Cat.toDynamoDBTableItemInput(catResponse)
    console.log(input);
    return DynamoDB.putItem(input).promise()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Inserted cat ID ' + catResponse.cat_id.toString());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }))

}

Router.use(http.get('/', handler))
Router.use(http.get('/index.html', handler))

Router.use(serve(paths.assets))

Router.use(http.get('*', handler))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. because of how lambda works: when it reaches the end, it not only returns whatever it is you want to return, it also kills the process. So if that happens too quickly, your call does not even have enough time to go through at all before being killed and the items are not created in your DB.
2. yes, but you are adding complexity for no valid reason. Granted you can call another lambda (using invokeAsync for example), but you would have the exact same issue as above. Also, DynamoDB is quite (read: *very*) fast for such simple operations, probably even faster than invoking a lambda.

   However if you are concerned about speed, what you might want to do instead of calling several times putItem if you need to write several items, is to call batchWriteItem instead, allowing you to write up to 25 items in a single call: so instead of 25 round-trips of networking latency for 25 items, you will indeed only have 1 single call writing 25 items at once: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property
3. not familiar with this particular setup nor koa in general, so I'm not sure what `render` usually does or how it behaves on Lambda. But if you fear that render "stops" what follows from happening, you could do something like the following instead, which has the added benefit of being more explicit in the order of the operations (`get the cats, THEN write them to DB, THEN return the body`)

```js
// Try Pet API
await fetch(url)...

// Enter item into DynamoDB
await Promise.all(...)

// Render response body 
ctx.body = render(getCatsResponse, App, ctx.request.path)
```

Comment: wrt "you are adding complexity for no valid reason" - 
I wouldn't be awaiting on the response of the other lambda, though - this would just be invoking the lambda and not caring about the response... is the operation faster to write into DynamoDB and wait for a response or to invoke a lambda?

Comment: can you please expand on "enough time to go through at all" - what does "go through" mean?

Comment: and finally, "because of how lambda works" - is this just learned from experience, or is there some documentation that speaks to the specifics of what you're saying here? thanks!